# Using Express/EJS to serve images. The image icon shows up but not the images

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to show images from a hardcoded data set. Name and Image, and then call it with JS on a projects page. The name call works, but the images will not show up. Only the icon place holder.

```
**INDEX** 
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var projects = 

app.use('./views/projects', projects);

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('landing', { title: 'Iron Eagle' });
});

// Get Projects Info for Database
router.get('/projects', function(req, res){
    var projects = [
        {name: 'Placeholder', image:'root/public/assets/testing.jpg'},
        {name: 'Placeholder', image:'https://www.pexels.com/photo/sand-earth-building-construction-95687'},
        {name: 'Placeholder', image:'https://www.pexels.com/photo/sand-earth-building-construction-95687'}      
    ]
    res.render('projects', {projects:projects});
});

module.exports = router;
// module.exports = projects;


**PROJECTS**
<h1>
    This is the projects page
</h1>

<% projects.forEach(function(projects){ %>
    <div>
        <h4>
            <%= projects.name %>
        </h4>
        <img src="<%= projects.image %>">
    </div>

<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Pexels image urls do not reference the image file but the webpage.

Perhaps try this url instead:
https://images.pexels.com/photos/95687/pexels-photo-95687.jpeg

Also, for your testing image you will need to tell express your serve static files from your public directory:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

...then update your url to:

```
var projects = [
  { name: 'Placeholder', image:'/assets/testing.jpg' },
  // ...
]
```

More info here:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

I hope this helps.